# 50 People All over the World hit web app versus 50 people on the Same LAN? Any difference?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, router

At my office we use a LAN (connected to internet through Comcast) and 30-50 people all accessed a web app (on Heroku) simultaneously. The server responded as if it had been hit by 50K people. Am I barking up the wrong tree, or would it make a difference if 50 people on an office network hit an app at the same time versus 50 people spread across the globe?

Apologies for such a vague question, but it only just occurred to me as a possibility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one difference that comes to mind is that on your LAN you may all have the same public IP address. The remote server might have classified 50 simultaneous connections from the same IP as a DoS attack and started blocking them. (Or it might be doing something with IP hashing, and treating all the users as if they were one and encountering some problem with locks/race conditions). (Really, a completely unsubstantiated wild guess...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably barking up the wrong tree.  It would make no difference at all.

Sounds like a bug in your webapp if it's reporting 50k instead of correctly reporting 50.  Although you haven't really said what is reporting this exactly.

In which case if it's a code problem you need to post some code over at stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks. 50K being an exaggeration, meaning even the simplest read/write operations timed out. Since it's Heroku I thought maybe it was due to request being routed to idle Dynos that needed to spin up, but according to Heroku, that is only the case if your app utilizes only a single Dyno. On Cedar, with Rails 3.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell what happened from the heroku logs. Depending on the app if the logs are not showing that the web&worker processes are the problem you may need to shard the database layer.